# Lotus ruby issue with db create and gem.lock

Tags: ruby, rake, hanami

Hello I have a problem when I do Lotus db create with the bookshelf's tutorial

> lotus db create enter code here WARN: Unresolved specs during
>   Gem::Specification.reset:
>         rack (>= 1.0, >= 1.0.0, ~> 1.5) WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs. Please report a bug if this causes problems.

Comment: Firstly, can you please tell me what version of lotus you use?

Secondly, is there anything related to Rails here? I see you tag this question with rails tag

Comment: Can you try with "bundle exec lotus ..."? (proposed by Sebastjan Hribar on the lotus chat)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and solved it from the [lotus discussion board](https://discuss.lotusrb.org/t/problem-with-db-create/142) like so:

```
gem uninstall rack # (remove all versions; yes disregard the complaints)
gem install rack
```

Seems to be a rack conflict.